# Executing sql strings from csv into mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I've created a huge .csv with only one column, each column is a valid sql string update like:

```
UPDATE TBL SET LAST = 0 WHERE ID = 1534781;
```

Is there a way to execute each row as a single sql query? Also, I'm using datagrip, if anyone knows of a sort of tool I would be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a file against your database in DataGrip just use the context menu when observing your file in `Files` tool window

[image]

Comment: I can't find this interface, FIles tool windows, where is it?

Comment: Press Ctrl/Cmd + 2 and then attach the folder with your file there.https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2019/01/30/working-with-files-in-datagrip/

Comment: Thanks! in my case, ubuntu 18, and Datagrip 2018.3 it is ALT+2 , I will update because it was really helpfull

Answer (score 2):

A CSV file that contains one column is just called a "file." :-)

The most common way of executing a series of SQL statements in a file is with the command-line mysql client:

```
mysql -e "source myfile.csv"
```

Comment: Only caveat with this answer is if this csv file does anything special if it needs to escape a character, like a newline or comma. If every line is nearly identical to the example, you're right though.

Comment: Indeed it is working, I'll let you know when it is finished :D! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

How about script:

```
    begin 
      update ...
      update ...
      update ...
      ...
    end;
```